# Use components from symfony 2.0 in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, routes

Is it possible to use components from symfony 2.0 in symfony 1.4 
project. If so, would you explain how to do it right?

I want to use new Routing in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I would doubt that anything from S2 will work in S1.x. Symfony2 will only work with PHP 5.3 and greater and uses a totally different architecture from 1.4. 
As the routing is a key component of the architecture then the chances of it working in a totally different architecture would be vanishingly small. Probably just as well to just use S2 if you want it's routing.